# Apache airflow: setting catchup to False is not working

Tags: scheduler, airflow

I have a DAG created on Apache airflow. It seems the scheduler is configured to run it from June 2015 (By the way. I do not know why, but it is a new DAG I created and I didn't backfill it, I only backfilled other dags with different DAG IDs with these date intervals, and the scheduler took those dates and backfilled my new dag. I'm starting to work with airflow).

(Update: I realized DAG is backfilled because the start date is set on the DAG default config, although this does not explain the behaviour I expose below)

I'm trying to stop the scheduler to run all the DAG executions from that date. `airflow backfill --mark_success tutorial2 -s '2015-06-01' -e '2019-02-27'` command is giving me database errors (see below), so I'm trying to set catchup to False.

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such
> table: job [SQL: 'INSERT INTO job (dag_id, state, job_type,
> start_date, end_date, latest_heartbeat, executor_class, hostname,
> unixname) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters:
> ('tutorial2', 'running', 'BackfillJob', '2019-02-27 10:52:37.281716',
> None, '2019-02-27 10:52:37.281733', 'SequentialExecutor',
> '08b6eb432df9', 'airflow')] (Background on this error at:
> http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

So I'm using another approach. What I've tried:

1. Setting catchup_by_default = False in airflow.cfg and restarting the
   whole docker container.
2. Setting catchup = False on my python DAG file and launching the file
   with python again.

What I'm seeing on the web UI:

DAG's executions are being launched starting in June 2015:
[![DAG's executions are being launched starting in June 2015.][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hlL9.png

Catchup is set to False on DAG's configuration:

[![Catchup is set to False on DAG's configuration][2]][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E01Cc.png

So I don't understand why those DAG's executions are being launched.

Thank you

DAG code:

```
"""
Code that goes along with the Airflow tutorial is located at:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py
"""
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2015, 6, 1),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'catchup' : False,
    # 'queue': 'bash_queue',
    # 'pool': 'backfill',
    # 'priority_weight': 10,
    # 'end_date': datetime(2016, 1, 1),
}

dag = DAG(
    'tutorial2', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='* * * * *')

# t1, t2 and t3 are examples of tasks created by instantiating operators
t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='print_date',
    bash_command='date',
    dag=dag)

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='sleep',
    bash_command='sleep 5',
    retries=3,
    dag=dag)

templated_command = """
    {% for i in range(5) %}
        echo "{{ ds }}"
        echo "{{ macros.ds_add(ds, 7)}}"
        echo "{{ params.my_param }}"
    {% endfor %}
"""

t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id='templated',
    bash_command=templated_command,
    params={'my_param': 'Parameter I passed in'},
    dag=dag)

t2.set_upstream(t1)
t3.set_upstream(t1)
```

Comment: `default_args` are passed to the tasks, so if you changed it afterwards, i suggest you change the dag version as well. Suffix it with `_v2` and see if that works.

Comment: When you say changing the version, do you mean creating a new dag with a new dag id (suffixed with _v2) to reload default args? // By the way, I guess catchup argument should be only used by the scheduler, not by the tasks, right?

Comment: I've created a new DAG with catchup = False in default args, I'm not updating default args in any place, and it still behaves the same way, DAG runs are scheduled starting at 2015-06-01 without backfilling the DAG, I'm very confused with this behaviour

Comment: Yes, I meant to create a new DAG. `catchup=False` should work as expected. What Airflow version are you using?

Comment: I am using v 1.10.2 via docker-compose containers.

Comment: Can you paste the DAG definition file contents in the question? From this I can't think of a reason for this, so maybe that helps.

Comment: Yes, of course. It is the tutorial code taken from airflow docs. I only changed the execution period to execute every minute and added the catchup = False parameter

Comment: Ok, I see now that start date is set in the DAG so it is the reason why it is scheduled I guess, but catchup should be used to not run executions from start date, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Start date shouldn't make your DAG run a backfill if you have `catchup=False`.

Comment: For your `SQLAlchemy.exc.OperationalError`, you must run (from shell) `airflow upgradedb` as told by **@Kaxil Naik** himself; read [point(9)](https://medium.com/datareply/airflow-lesser-known-tips-tricks-and-best-practises-cf4d4a90f8f). Rest assured because *It wouldn't delete any existing metadata from `Airflow`'s backend-db*

Comment: By the way, the start_time parameter by itself shoundn't backfill the DAG to run since that time, right? Why was the DAG executions launched? I'm now creating a new DAG with start_time = now() and and an interval period to run everyminuto and it is not executed (maybe because it is not backfilled)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you actually need to specify the catchup at the `dag` level, not pass it in through `default_args`. (The latter doesn't really make sense anyway, since those are the default args for the tasks. You couldn't have some tasks catch up and others not.)

Try this:

```
dag = DAG(
    'tutorial2', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='* * * * *', catchup=False)
```

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work, although there is still an unanswered issue. The configuration is not properly applied from airflow.cfg file default config.

Comment: This doesn't work either...

Comment: catchup=False  should be after "schedule_interval" ?